# Android open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-gallery, onactivityresult

I'm trying to pick an image from the gallery and when i pick it i get this error:

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

in the manifest i already set the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But i still have the error and i can't view the image in the ImageView. This is the code anyway:

```
public void loadImagefromGallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firstImg);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
```

where `loadImagefromGallery()` method is called in a button on click. I can't understand the problem..

EDIT:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                    return;
                }
                loadImagefromGallery();

            }
        });
```

This is my onClick() method. i added the request for permission but still get the same error

Comment: what's your targetSdkVersion ? if its 23 try changing it to a lower version and then check

Comment: this:     compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Comment: Please post your AndroidManifest xml file here; I had the same problem last night but I noticed I had not requested the WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION

Comment: are you testing on device with android 6.0 ?

Comment: Yes I'm testing with Android 6.could be the problem?

Comment: I faced a similar problem while querying the contacts although had given the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, this coluld be related to the new **run time permissions** feature in android 6.0, as a workaround you could try changing the `targetSDKVersion` to `22` just for testing purpose

Comment: this will give you more idea http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

Comment: Check my edit please

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi your link was very usefull thanks! I solved.  Here's the tutorial i followed http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en . Perfect

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Comment: I posted the solution, maybe someone else has the same problem

Comment: you can also post that as an answer that seems to be more useful :)

Comment: Yes, that's true, done :)

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: I want to post my way to solve the problem. This is what i've done:

```
private void insertDummyImageWrapper() {
    int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to SdCard",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
    loadImagefromGallery();
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .create()
        .show();
}
```

And in the fab i called the insertDummyImageWrapper() method

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                        return;
                    }
                    insertDummyImageWrapper();

                }
            });
```

Now it 's working perfectly